# Search number in MongoDB and NodejS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I have simple data like this in MongoDB

```json
{
    "_id": "eE-sOpegt",
    "isApproved": true,
    "isDttotWarningFlagRaised": false,
    "fullname": "Gerald Bendryandre Sihotang",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$Uib2qpgLrzYAM4KmPdX/bOP6pBozJ6SDadCBSYoXY1JNcSJI7/3xC",
    "phone": 6281234567890,
    "registrationStep": 2,
    "role": "user",
    "__v": 0
}
```

See the `phone`, its a `number` **NOT** a `string`.
I want to search this data with one field using `paginate`
Here is the code:

```java
User.paginate({
    $or: [
      { fullname: new RegExp('.*' + req.query.q + '.*', 'i') },
      { email: new RegExp('.*' + req.query.q + '.*', 'i') },

      /* Here is the problem 
         When I comment this phone, it works and return data.
         When its not commented, returns error
      */
      // { phone: {$eq: Number(req.query.q) } }
    ]
  }
...
```

I call this API using postman with this URL
`localhost:8000/getUsersByQuery?q=gerald`

It works when I comment the `{ phone }`
But it returns error when the `phone` is not commented
How can I get the data with the `phone` number?

Comment: can you share the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in the Phone field you are passing string instead of number that's why its given error.
So you need to check whether the first `req.query.q` is numeric or not. Then you need to pass it in `Number()`.

Here you can use the below function for checking the same.

```
function isNumeric(num)
{ 
   return !isNaN(num)
}
```

Below is some Example of isNan function.

```
isNaN(num)         // returns true if the variable does NOT contain a valid number
isNaN(123)         // false
isNaN('123')       // false
isNaN('1e10000')   // false (This translates to Infinity, which is a number)
isNaN('foo')       // true
isNaN('10px')      // true
```